# How to get hiltViewModel from Activity?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I am trying to get a view model in two places, one in the MainActivity using:

```
val viewModel:MyViewModel by viewModels()
```

The Other place is inside a compose function using:

```
val viewModel:MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()
```

When I debug, it seems that those are two different objects. Is there anyway where I can get the same object in two places ?

Comment: Are you using Navigation? Each route has it's own scope of view models. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69002254/3585796) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64961032/3585796)

Comment: what I am trying to do is this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50533585/18028117 the problem is, I get the view model in the activity to subscribe to permission requests, but what is actually passed to the compose is a new instance of MyViewModel which is not subscribed to it's Observable/LiveData

Comment: Check out [Accompanist Permissions](https://google.github.io/accompanist/permissions/), you don't need a view model to manage permissions

Comment: Amazing! thanks @PhilipDukhov

Answer (score 8):

Even though you solved your issue without needing the view model, the question remained unanswered so I am posting this in case someone else finds it helpful.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68971296/6640693) explains how view model scopes are shared and how you can override it.

In case you are using Navigation component, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68857871/6640693) should help. However, if you don't want to pass down view models or override the provided `ViewModelStoreOwner`s, you can access the parent activity's view model in any child composable like below.

```
val composeView = LocalView.current
val activityViewModel = composeView.findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner()?.let {
    hiltViewModel<MyViewModel>(it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding with @Altline.

In the following way we can get non null viewmodel in the compose view

```
val context = LocalView.current
val mainViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(context as ViewModelStoreOwner).get< MyViewModel >()
}
```